# cookieless session temporary internet files (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, caching, session, cookieless

background:
I work on an asp.net web application that is on a company intranet. cookieless="true" is set in the web.config in the sessions configuration. The application is launched off a page and can run in several different modes (a different link for each mode). It is a business requirement that multiple instances of the application can be run at the same time for comparison and so each browser spawn must have a new session...anyway...

Checking the Temporary Internet Files folder on my pc, each image used in the application that is being viewed is downloaded multiple times because the session id is in the url (I assume) and is causing the cached image not to be found.
The Internet Address field for the same image is in the form http://mywebserver/mywebapp/(S(......))/images/xxxxxxx.gif

To continue having cookieless sessions, is the best way to move images etc into a directory outside of the web application on the same (or different) server? e.g. http://mywebserver/mywebappresource/images/xxxxxxx.gif

any suggesions most welcome! thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does the URL for the gif need to change just because the page that it's embedded into changes? If you could keep the gif URL constant then it would be cached as you hope.

That is pretty much the same thing as what you are suggesting, with changing the directory for the images to outside the web application. You could always do this with a redirection rule within the web server if it was too awkward to do within the application.

I think what I'm trying to say is "Yes".

Comment: moving images to another domain/pool does have the side-effect of allowing for more connections from the browser, and a potentially faster load time.